# Set points according to coordinates using QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, point, layers, coordinates

How can I set points according to coordinates?

I know that you can see the exact coordinates when you set a point. But I just want to type or copy the coordinates in to set a point. For an example how can I set a point exactly at this point: 53.581282, 10.0309379?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Advanced digitizing tool to lock the coordinates, then place a point anywhere:

[image]

But if you have many points to place, you can save them in a csv table and add as a delimited text layer.

Another option is to use a virtual layer:

```
select MakePoint(10.0309379, 53.581282, 4326) as geometry
```

[image]